# Installing jdk8 on ubuntu- "unable to locate package" update doesn't fix

Tags: java, linux

I've been trying to install the jdk on my ubuntu after downloading it.

first I've used: `sudo apt-get update`

then: `sudo apt-get install jdk*`  (because I didn't want to write the whole long name).

it didn't work- printed the message in the title.

I thought the problem might me with the directory I'm executing from (I've executed it from the Downloads directory in which the file exists), so I've tried executing the same command (`sudo apt-get install jdk*`) from the home directory (root directory). Then it worked.. the whole installation took about 5 minutes and it looked like it was installing a lot of things I didn't ask for.

I wasn't sure it installed what I needed to I went back to the Downloads directory where the jdk8 package was located and like the first time ran the command from there. the same message as before... couldn't locate the package.

What have I done wrong ? Obviously it wasn't installed because when I've checked the version of java (java -version) it didn't show jdk8 was installed.

Thank you if you've taken the time to read to this point :)

Comment: Here is an excellent tutorial for installing JDK 8 on Ubuntu: [http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux). Though a bit long, it's very thorough and has worked wonders for me. EDIT: Java 8 can now be installed via a PPA. Use vikasdumca's answer.

Comment: The Oracle JDK license has changed from 16th of April 2019, according to a forum you need to create an account on Oracle to use it. but, follow the steps on this link.
[This does put a smile on my face](https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-18-10/)

Answer (score 53):

Command Line option - Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Then in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

When there are multiple Java installations on your System, the Java version to use as default can be chosen. To do this, execute the following command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

Edit - Manual Java Installation

Download oracle jdk

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

Extract zip into desired folder

```
 e.g  /usr/local/  after extract /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65
```

Setup

```
sudo update-alternatives --install  /usr/bin/java java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install  /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/javac 1
sudo update-alternatives --install  /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/javaws 1

sudo update-alternatives --set  java /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set  javac /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set  javaws /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/javaws
```

Edit /etc/environment set JAVA_HOME path for external applications like Eclipse and Idea

Comment: Great! This should be the best answer to the actual question!

Answer (score 11):

For me non of the above worked and I had to do as below, and it worked,

sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa

and then,

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/644188/updating-jdk-7-to-8-unable-to-locate-package

Comment: Dec 2019, this seems to be the most suitable solution. 
Ubuntu 18.4

Answer (score 5):

For those who had trouble with the [apt-get](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-openjdk-8-ubuntu-14-04-12-04-lts/), or with [the long instruction](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux).
I solved it in a relatively painless way.

1. Download the installer from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8_java/precise/main/base/oracle-java8-installer), or direct download [link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/pool/main/o/oracle-java8-installer/oracle-java8-installer_8u51+8u51arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb)
2. `$ sudo dpkg -i oracle-java8-installer_8u51+8u51arm-1-webupd8-0_all.deb`

Answer (score 4):

If you get a

`sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`

then you need to run the following command

`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties`

Answer (score 4):

It's same as vikasdumca's steps, but thought to share the link.

run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

this would install oracle java 8 on ubuntu properly.

find it from this [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

you can find more info on "Managing Java" or "Setting the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable" from the post.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu defaults to the OpenJDK packages.  If you want to install Oracle's JDK, then you need to visit their download page, and grab the package from there.

Once you've installed the Oracle JDK, you also need to update the following (system defaults will point to OpenJDK):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/my/path/to/oracle/jdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If you want the Oracle JDK to be the default for your system, you will need to remove the OpenJDK packages, and update your profile environment variables.

Comment: I did. I downloaded it from oracle.

Comment: But the problem is I couldn't even install it. it doesn't show.

Comment: Also, don't do jdk* when installing packages - it will install a lot of stuff you might not need.  If the package is in the current directory, just use tab completion.

Comment: Which file did you download?  You will need to use `dpkg` to install it, not apt-get.

Comment: The tab doesn't work used in the apt-get to autofill the whole name. tried.

I'm new to linux, isn't dpkg an older version? I saw people use apt-get and it worked for them :(

Comment: Autocomplete works on files in the directory (not package names), which you mentioned you had downloaded...

Comment: apt-get is an extension of sorts of dpkg, allowing you to retrieve packages from a repository.  dpkg is responsible for managing them on your system.

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install  oracle-java12-installer
```

that works fine

Answer (score 0):

I used another repository for oracle java.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install  oracle-java11-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

'Universe' repository needs to be enabled. Then

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Please refer [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233238/why-is-apt-unable-to-locate-openjdk-package-on-ubuntu-20-04).