# oracle java 8 installer getting failed on ubuntu 18.04 through dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, java-8, dockerfile

I am setting up java through Docker file to install oracle java 8 and getting failed as java 8 installed not available through apt-get

tried many suggestions given on Stack Overflow which directs to update the license and other methods

```
Unpacking sudo (1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up sudo (1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1) ...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-set-default
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289482/installing-jdk8-on-ubuntu-unable-to-locate-package-update-doesnt-fix might help

Comment: what steps you tried to install it ? Dockerfile ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650812/how-to-install-oraclejdk8-through-docker-file-in-ubuntu/56659604#56659604 helpful? `curl -L -b "oraclelicense=a" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -O`

Answer (score 0):

Snippet from one of my dockerfile with oracle java.
I hope you can use the same.

```
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
  add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer=${version} && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer
```